# Where are the results of recursion stored in javascript?

Tags: javascript, recursion

When I call a recursive on function, where do the results of the call go?

```js
function reverse(str){ 
    if (str.length == 1){ 
      return str;
    } 
  rev = reverse(str.substr(1)) + str.charAt(0);
}

reverse("String"); 
console.log(rev); // ----> "undefinedS" - Only the last call is saved.
```

If I just return the value it seems fine.  Where is the result getting stored?

```js
function reverse(str){ 
    if (str.length == 1){ 
      return str
    } 
  return reverse(str.substr(1)) + str.charAt(0);
}

reverse("String") // ----> "gnirtS"
```

Comment: It isn't getting stored anywhere, if you don't have a `return` in a function it'll run until complete and the return value will be undefined

Comment: Here's a hint: Without returning anything, the call to `reverse` will return `undefined`. So you get `undefinedS` because you're concatenating `undefined` (the result of `reverse(str.substr(1))`) and `S` (the result of `str.charAt(0)`).

Comment: it is not undefined ...it is undefinedS the first operation results.

Comment: There's a difference between what the function **returns** and what you assign to the global variable `rev`.

Comment: Your function is not returning anything therefore on your second call, it will return `undefined`, which is why you get `undefinedS`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your first version**

`rev` is stored in the global namespace, and is overwritten each time the function `reverse` is called.

The recursion stops when the string's length is one, after having taken only the last n-1 characters. As a result, the final character is the only character in the string, `S`, and that is what `str.charAt(0)` gives.

Since the function `reverse` does not return a value when `str` is length 0 (which is what happens with `"S".substr(1)`) the value of `reverse(str.substr(1))` is `undefined`.

This results in `undefinedS`.

**Your second version**

This version creates a call stack whereby the string is slowly taken apart by n-1 (where n is its length) until its length is 1. At that point the stack is unwound, causing each letter from the last to the first to be returned. Each function call as its own Execution context, whereby a Variable Environment is holding the value of each string.

The result of the callstack unwinding is `gnirtS`.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaner Look code

```
function reverse(str){ 
   return (str.length == 1)? str : reverse(str.substr(1)) + str.charAt(0);
}
```

Comment: Or by arrow function :) `var reverse = str => (str.length == 1)? str : reverse(str.substr(1)) + str.charAt(0);`